# sql update command with timestamp

Tags: java, sql, database

i try to execute some sql update command that should update some column to 0

my table is

```
person: email(string),name(string),isconnect(string).
imalive:email(string),lastseen(timestamp (2011-10-03 22:46:00)).
```

now im try this:

```
UPDATE persons SET isconnect=0 WHERE not exists (select imalive.email from imalive WHERE lastseen>'2011-10-14 13:43:32.876')
```

but sometime its work and some time it's not

im runnig hsql (if it's matter) and the server is in java.

does anyone have a clue or better option.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "some time it's not [working]". Do you get an error? Do you get incorrectly updated rows? What happens if you run the select statement on its own?

Comment: it'w just say "no changes has made" (this is the result when i run it through DbVisualizer), no error or somting, i try to find the role when it's happend, but didnt find yet.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE persons SET isconnect=0 WHERE not exists (select imalive.email from imalive WHERE datediff(lastseen,'2011-10-14 13:43:32.876') > 0)`

Comment: im using some DB TOOL (DbVisualizer) to test my quary. and i try your but it's not know what is datediff. thanks